# Is logistic loss function L-smooth?

Tags: optimization, lipschitz-functions, gradient-descent

Assume $f(x)$ has an L-Lipschitz continuous gradient say $L$ i.e there is a constant L>0 such that 
$$\|\nabla f(x) - \nabla f(y)\|_2 \le L\|x-y\|_2$$ for any $x,y$.

Does $f(\beta) = \sum_{i=1}^n Y_i X_i \beta-\log{[1+\exp{(X_i \beta)}]}$ have an L-Lipschitz continuous gradient?
$Y_i \in \mathbb R$ ,$X_i, \beta \in \mathbb R^p\ \forall i \in [1..n]$  where $p\ge 1 $.

What I have done:
$$\nabla f(\beta) = \sum_{i=1}^n [Y_i-h_\beta(X_i)]X_i^T$$
where $h_B(x) = \frac{1}{1+ \exp(-x \cdot \beta)}$. Basically, it is a sigmoid function.

$||\sum_{i=1}^n (h_{{\beta}_2}(X_i) - h_{{\beta}_1}(X_i))X_i^T||\le L||{\beta}_1-{\beta}_2||$

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: what are $X_i,Y_i$? Just some constants?

Comment: @CalvinKhor Yes, the logic is the same as logistic regression I edited the question

Comment: You wrote $\beta \in R^p$. is this $\mathbb R^p$ i.e. real vector space of dimension $p\ge 1$? Then what is $\exp(X_i \beta)?$ is it $\exp(X_i \cdot \beta)$?

Comment: @CalvinKhor I edited. yes in real space and dot product

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, WLOG $Y_i = 0$. Second, its enough to check that

$$g:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R,\ g(t) = \log(1+\exp(t))$$
has Lipschitz gradient, and it does because its second derivative is bounded.
Then the composition of Lipschitz maps is Lipschitz, and your thing is

$$ \nabla f(\beta) = -g'(h(\beta))X_i^T,\quad h(\beta) = X_i \cdot \beta$$

Comment: Thanks for the explanation but how do I find L?

Comment: @Pumpkin You can follow the proofs of the statements I used, everything is explicit, nothing like axiom of choice or zorn's lemma is used

Comment: @CalvinKhor could you please expand? 'your thing' is not very clear to me at least. The Lipschitz constant shouldn't depend on \beta, right?

Comment: Why is it unclear? I already wrote what ‘your thing’ refers to, in the LHS? Why are you getting dependence on beta? @AmitPortnoy

Comment: @CalvinKhor X_i \dot \beta seem to depend on beta. In any case, obviously, you know more about this problem than I do, that's we ask if you could please be more explicit.

Comment: @AmitPortnoy I'm asking you to show your calculation because I don't know what is not clear. Easier example: $f(\beta) = \beta$ also depends on $\beta$, but the Lipschitz constant does not.

Comment: @CalvinKhor I don't have a calculation, I'm trying to work out what is 'your thing' and what is the Lipschitz constant.

Comment: @AmitPortnoy As I said in the earlier comment, "your thing" is the LHS of the following line, which is $\nabla f(\beta)$. This is clear also because this is the function that OP is talking about. And I have no idea how you expect to find a constant without any calculation!